# Which is the better way of writing the __str__ method for printing deque in my code with respect to performance?

Tags: python, string, printing

1st way:

```
from collections import deque

class Stack:

def __init__(self):
    self.s = deque()

def push(self, data):
    self.s.append(data)

def pop(self):
    try:
        self.s.pop()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def __str__(self):
    l = []
    for i in self.s:
        l.append(str(i))
    if l == []:
        return 'Stack is Empty'
    else:
        return ' '.join(l)
```

2nd way:

```
from collections import deque

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = deque()

    def push(self, data):
        self.s.append(data)

    def pop(self):
        try:
            self.s.pop()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.s)
```

Also it will be nice if someone can give me the **time complexity** of both the **str** method to make it more clear. Also which one will be your personal favourite. It will be nice if someone can provide a better way of doing it.

Comment: If you want performance, definitely the 1st way is not the way to go, don't know about how visual 2nd way is though

Comment: Why are you using a deque here, instead of a list? The list pop and append operations are constant time from the end if the list, so the deque comes with no advantage. Anyway, I would assume both methods are O(n), assuming that the items in the stack have a constant time string method. But certainly, relying on. The built in method will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `timeit` module to measure the performance:

```
from collections import deque
from timeit import timeit

class Stack1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = deque()

    def push(self, data):
        self.s.append(data)

    def pop(self):
        try:
            self.s.pop()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def __str__(self):
        l = []
        for i in self.s:
            l.append(str(i))
        if l == []:
            return 'Stack is Empty'
        else:
            return ' '.join(l)

class Stack2:

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = deque()

    def push(self, data):
        self.s.append(data)

    def pop(self):
        try:
            self.s.pop()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.s)

stack1 = Stack1()
stack1.push(1)
stack1.push(2)
stack1.push(3)

stack2 = Stack2()
stack2.push(1)
stack2.push(2)
stack2.push(3)


def test_func1():
    s = str(stack1)

def test_func2():
    s = str(stack2)

print(timeit('test_func1()', globals=globals(), number=1_000_000))
print(timeit('test_func2()', globals=globals(), number=1_000_000))
```

Output is (1 million calls each):

```
1.818193725997844
1.463878423001006
```

So Stack2 with simple `str()` call is ~20% faster.